# Magento - error importing images with import/Export module and symbolic links

Tags: magento, import, capistrano

Capistrano is in charge of deploying my magento in all environments. The structure we work with is as follows:

```
Website
 | current
 |  | media ---ln---> /var/www/website/aplication/shared/media
 |  |  | import
 |  |  |  | p
 |  |  |  | | a
 |  |  |  | | | patata.jpg
```

When I try to import a CSV with a list of products with the image gallery, the images aren't imported. I have noticed that it's not possible to upload images from the backend either when "media" is a symbolic link. 
What can I do to make it work with symbolic links? Has anyone had this problem before?

Answer (score 0):

You should try the [MAgmi Image attributes processor](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Image_attributes_processor).
It allows images to be uploaded even from a third party URL.